# JavaScript Object questions

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have an object called options. Inside the object, I have one key named imageTypes. I am trying to test if png matches any one of the imageTypes. What am I doing wrong here. Thanks for the input guys!

```
    var options = {
         imageTypes: /\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i
    }
    if (options.imageTypes.test(image/png)) {
        //do stuff
    }
```

Comment: Is image/png perhaps an object? It looks to me like your only problem is missing quotes to make it a string.
'image/png'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Info

Hope this will help you understand what you are trying to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/pratik136/YZ5ZD/

```
var options = {
    imageTypes1: /\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
    imageTypes2: /image\/(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i
};
if (options.imageTypes1.test('.png')
    && options.imageTypes2.test('image/png')) {
    //do stuff
    showResult('true');
} else {
    showResult('false');
}
```

`imageTypes1` is a Regex that will match a string like `.png`, while `imageTypes2` is trying to match `image/png`

---

### So What's Wrong

The syntax error in your code sample is the missing quotes around `image/png`, while the logical error is that you are using the wrong Regular Expression.

Comment: @jensiepoo - You are welcome :) But have you now actually understood what was wrong? Ask if still in doubt.

Comment: @jensiepoo - Do not forget to accept an answer if your question was resolved satisfactorily. This is the core of a Q&A format!

Answer (score 1):

You're using a math operation (i.e. division) before you're calling test. This will result in the RegEx being called over a number, which doesn't really work that well.

If image is a variable of yours, drop the `/png`. Or if you're trying to compare 'image/png' (i.e. the string), then you will have to enter the quotes before and after.

Tested it out on jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kr5dn/), you can find the results in the console output.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test "image/png" as a string, then you'll have to change your regex as it now checks for the image extension in a dot format.

```
var options = {
    imageType: function(pic) {
      return (/^image\/(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i).test(pic);
    }
};

// returns true
console.log(options.imageType('image/png'));
```